# php strtotime disregarding hour, minutes, seconds

Tags: php, mysql, database, strtotime

I have a date time coming in from a select form with the format of `12:00 PM Sat Mar 15` purely for aesthetic reasons. The PHP `strtotime` function converts this to (and more than likely rightfully so): `1394866800`.

However, when I prepare the time for my database `$db_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time_req);` I get `2014-03-15 00:00:00`. Is there a way to keep my visually appealing time display yet enter the correct format in my MySQL database?

Comment: [DateTime::convertFromFormat()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Comment: _“purely for aesthetic reasons”_ – the `option` element has a `value` attribute apart from its text content … you should only use the latter for your “aesthetic reasons”, then you would not have to bother with stuff like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your input is in a non-standard format, because the time comes first, then the day of the week, then the month and day of the month. You need to tell PHP how to interpret this.

You can use [**`date_create_from_format`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), like so:

```
$formatted_date = '12:00 PM Sat Mar 15';
// to use your POST data, use $formatted_date = $_POST['time_req'];
echo date_create_from_format('H:i A D M j', $formatted_date)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

**Output:**

```
2014-03-15 12:00:00
```

Note: the above is the one-liner, procedural version of the method `DateTime::createFromFormat`, as pointed out by @MarkBaker in the comments. You could also do:

```
$formatted_date = '12:00 PM Sat Mar 15';
// to use your POST data, use $formatted_date = $_POST['time_req'];

// create an object
$mydate = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i A D M j', $formatted_date);
// invoke the format method
echo $mydate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: upvoted this one because of the greater context and simplified method for attaining the correct format for insert.

Comment: I keep getting "Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in... This is despite me casting the incoming $_POST vartiable to string: $time_req = (string)$_POST['time_req']; I'm sure this is the right answer though. Any thoughts?

Comment: It's not clear to me from this comment which part is your actual code. Just put `$_POST['time_req']` where you see `'12:00 PM Sat Mar 15'` in my answer; no need to cast anything to a string. Example: `echo date_create_from_format('H:i A D M j', $_POST['time_req'])->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Comment: Edited my answer to try to clarify exactly how you can use this.

Comment: @EdCottrell Absolutely right kind friend. My mistake. +100 FedoraTips

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
$st = "12:00 PM Sat Mar 15";

$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i A D M j", $st);
$mysql_formatted = $datetime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```